# Detecting bills by using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

Is there any new or recent tutorials about using openCv in android studio. I would like to use that to create our capstone project. It is an app that should detect bills using its camera (or using an image) and determine its value.

I've created an app but now I'm stuck on how to use opencv because I don't have any experience using it before and I can't get any decent tutorials.

These is what I have created so far. (ignore the comments, me and my brother are trying to code this and he said that it is better to comment out some lines rather than erasing it).

activity_convert.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Convert">

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/cView"
        android:layout_width="343dp"
        android:layout_height="303dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Convert.java

```
package com.example.carlo.thesis;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Convert extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    private static String TAG = "Convert";
    JavaCameraView jview;
    Mat mRgba, imgGray, imgCanny, mHierarchy;
    Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255,0,0,255);
    static {
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded.");
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded.");
        }
    }
    BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status){
                case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:{
                    jview.enableView();

                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);

        jview = findViewById(R.id.cView);

        jview.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        jview.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
            if(jview!=null){
                jview.disableView();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(jview!=null){
            jview.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
            if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
                mLoaderCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
                OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallBack);
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mHierarchy = new Mat();


        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        imgGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        imgCanny = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

       // List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        final Mat dst = new Mat(mRgba.rows(), mRgba.cols(), mRgba.type());
        mRgba.copyTo(dst);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        final List<MatOfPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
        final Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

        Imgproc.findContours(dst, points, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
       /* Imgproc.Canny(mRgba, imgCanny, 50, 100);
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(imgCanny, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        Imgproc.findContours(imgCanny, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        Imgproc.drawContours(imgCanny, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);


        //Imgproc.findContours(mRgba, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);




        return contours.get(1);

        //return imgCanny;*/

        Mat mRgbaT = mRgba.t();
        Core.flip(mRgba.t(), mRgbaT, 1);
        Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaT, mRgba.size());

        return mRgbaT;
    }


}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you have any success? any link you can refer to  for detecting a bill with OpenCV in android?

Comment: sadly, I abandoned OpenCV and instead use Google text recognition with SurfaceView. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can find OpenCV Android demos on GitHub from here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android

OpenCV tutorials for Android, it has Eclipse steps.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/df8/tutorial_dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

You can also search for the OpenCV Android videos on the internet, it will help you learn quick.